# Reusable Card Format

Tags: trello

Is there a way to make a reusable card format?

For example I have card that always has the same 3 checklist items on it. I would like to be able to save a copy of if it, so I can add a new card like it with the checklist already part of it.

Comment: Is it possible to do this through the API? Make a small python script to create and populate a card.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The team is working on reusable cards, lists, boards, and checklists, beginning with checklists (the simplest case). It's been made known that users would want the option to save with checklists, members, etc.

There is a card for it here: https://trello.com/c/LIqasVwP

Answer (score 0):

This Chrome plugin enables you to copy boards or cards: https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/igdohpdnohikeonpipombhdepnmbigkl

It works on my machine. It should fill the gap until they get around to deploying it officially